# google appengine searching buckets to find a particular "content_type" text/csv

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I have multiple buckets and i would like to find a the buckets that store the csv files.  I do not know how to search buckets to find what i need. Is there a method to query the buckets to only find content type "`text/csv`."  Ultimately i am attempting to find the csv files blobkey that begins with "`encoded_gs_file:`"  Also, what is the relationship between the datastore and storage?

The blobstore viewer that i am running in localhost only shows the `encoded_gs_file` for images.  But i know that there should be a `encoded_gs_file` for the csv files.

When i visit the following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/datastore?kind=__GsFileInfo__
```

i can see the csv file type, but when i go to this url:

```
http://localhost:8000/datastore?kind=__BlobInfo__
```

the csv file does not appear.  I think if i can get the csv file to appear in the ____blobInfo____ endpoint, then i can download it

Answer (score 1):

There is not a specific method to search objects into a bucket, but what you can do is to search using different API methods for example using the JSON API:

1.List all the buckets on your project. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22edp44591%22%7D

2.Then, having the list of buckets you can list all the object in each one 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

3.Once you have the list of objects inside the bucket you can filter with you preferred programming language.

Basically you can do the same with the XML API here is the reference to it:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-methods

Or using the gsutil tool:
gsutil list  :to list all the bucket on your project: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets

gsutil ls -r gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/** : to list all the objects inside your project.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects

If you want to see examples about how to use the API with different code-languages go to the document Cloud Storage Client Libraries https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs

Comment: it gives the following error: `"error": { "code": 401,"message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access `

Comment: how are you  doing it? could you provide more details?

Comment: Hey Enrique, i try to enter it in the browser url.  I do not know how to use a key along wiith the url to get the premission

Comment: Could you provide me the of the blobstore viewer that you are using or the link to it?

Comment: the blobstore viewer, as i have recently learned, is only available in local development. I do not know why google does this.  They deprecated the function in production.  Is there a way i can use the enter the information along with a key in the browser to get the bucket information?

Comment: Currently there are 2 ways to do this, is that you create a program using the API provided in the response and the other one is through the Cloud Shell using gsutil commands.